# Unserialize a value obtained from the db on php

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization

I need to do something that I am sure it is simple, but I read and read information everywhere and can't find the solution for this. I know, I am a noob, but I really don't know what else to try now.

There is a line on one of the php files of my website's theme, that is like this:

```
global $post;
if (!is_page()) {$category_ID = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_category_permalink', true);}
    else {$category_ID =  '';}  
$category_parent = pa_category_top_parent_id ($category_ID);
```

The thing is that '_category_permalink' value on the database is not always an integer number, and I need it to. Sometimes the value is a serialized value, something like this:

```
a:1:{s:8:"category";s:2:"23";}
```

So, $category_ID sometimes is 23 (or any other number), and other times is a:1:{s:8:"category";s:2:"23";} (and other values too).

What I need to do is something that can check is the value obtained after that line is an integer or not. In case it is, I need to unserialize it and convert it to its corresponding integer number, stored in the "category" section of that serialized value (from my example, the number 23), so $category_ID will always be equal to an integer number and not a serialized value.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT & UPDATE:

This has been solved, the code ended up like this

```
if (!is_page()) { $category_ID = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_category_permalink', true); } else {$category_ID =  '';}    
global $wpdb;
$catmeta = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM MYDATABASENAMEHERE WHERE post_id = '".$post->ID."' AND meta_key LIKE '_category_permalink'",ARRAY_A);

if(strpos($catmeta['meta_value'],':{')!==false){
$catmeta = unserialize($catmeta['meta_value']);
$catmeta['meta_value'] = $catmeta['category'];
}

$category_parent = pa_category_top_parent_id ($catmeta['meta_value']);
```

Comment: You can check the value if numeric or not by `is_numeric()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if `$category_ID` is a number using `is_number()`.

If not, so use `unserialize()` to convert it to `array` and check `category`:

```
if (is_numeric($category_ID)) {
     # $category_ID is number, use it
     # your code here...
} else {
    # $category_ID is a serialized value
    $cat = unserialize($category_ID);
    $category_ID = intval($cat['category']);
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is the value is not always the same, so I can't add it like this. $str could be an integer, or a serialized value. Serialized formatting is the same, but is not the same exact value.

Comment: @Shinji3rd Check if `$category_ID` is a number first, as mentioned in my answer. If it is a number, so use it. Otherwise, continue with `unserialize()`. See my updated answer

Comment: Ok, is_number does not work. Instead, the command is is_numeric. But although by logic it should work, in this case it didn't. Finally, after much investigation, I found a solution. My original message has been edited to include it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry.
You can check if this is number by this code:

```
//check if is numeric
 if(is_numeric($category_parent)){
     $category_parent_id = $category_parent;
    } else {
    //if is array unserialize
     $category_parent_array = unserialize($category_parent);
     //use array to get the id
     $category_parent_id = $category_parent_array['category'];
    }
```

Comment: This code looked promising, and I tried it but it does not work. I've modified it a little however, because the value I need to be checked is $category_ID and not $category_parent, but it is strange because it seems it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
$data = unserialize('a:1:{s:8:"category";s:2:"23";}');
$category = $data['category'];
if( is_numeric($category) ){
    //Write code here if category is numeric (integer)
}else{
    //Write code here if category is string (not numeric)
}
```